# Can I explain the idea behind a Velcro tape using the name of these plant seeds? (photo)

Tags: words

**Introduction:** Long time ago, when I had no idea Velcro tape was called マジックテープ in Japanese I tried to suggest using it to my Japanese colleague. He had no idea about the word "Velcro", so I tried an example of [bur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bur), but I found Japanese people think of food when they hear ゴボウ ([burdock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctium)) rather than its seeds.

Now I have found these stuck to my jeans:

[image: Japanese burs]

(in reality they were greener, about 5 mm in size).

**Question:** What is the plant (or seeds) called in Japanese and is its feature of sticking to animals/human known well enough to use it as an explanation of the way Velcro tape works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The generic name you are lookig for would be 「ひっつき[虫]{むし}」 or 「くっつき虫」.

「ひっつく」 means "to adhere to".  「くっつく」 is its synonym.

http://matsue-hana.com/yasou/hittukimusi.html

As to your other question, I just remembered hearing somewhere long ago how Velcro was invented from the observation of these plants, but I think that is because  reading your question has triggered my memory.

「ひっつき虫のようにひっつくテープ」 would only be understood by those who are familiar with the word 「ひっつき虫」, which I feel like was in my active vocabulary as a kid but is not really there any more.

「マジックテープ」 would probably be the only word that every Japanese-speaker is familiar with.

Comment: マイナーな方言だと思ってましたが、[Wikipediaにも（俗語として）記事があった](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%B2%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8D%E8%99%AB)のでびっくり…

Comment: Velcro themselves [claim](http://www.velcro.com/About-Us/History.aspx) it was burr that inspired the tape. Several European languages (German, Norwegian, Polish) call the tape with a name derived from the word *burr* in their vernaculars, hence my immediate (failed) try with ゴボウ.

Comment: @l'électeur:  Why do you keep making all of your answers into community wikis?  I don't think your answers need [true community collaboration](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/).  If you're trying to be "humble" by not gaining any rep, I assure you no one cares.